# Convert stream or sequence to a stream or sequence of summaries

Tags: kotlin, java-stream, sequence

Using Kotlin, how would I transform a `Sequence` of detail objects into a `Sequence` of summary objects, where each summary object represents a fixed number of detailed objects? It's kind of like `map`, except it's not one-to-one and it's kind of like `reduce` except it's not to a single accumulator?

For example:

```
var hourlyInfo: Sequence<HourlyData> = ...
var dailyInfo: Sequence<DailySummary> = hourlyInfo.somethingMagical()
```

What about the same problem with a stream instead of a sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a known fixed number of items, you use `chunked` and then map. When the sequence is iterated, actual lists of each chunk of items will be allocated.

```
var dailyInfo: Sequence<DailySummary> = hourlyInfo
  .chunked(12)
  .map(::DailySummary) // for example if it has a constructor taking a List of 12 HourlyData
```

If the List of HourlyData isn't ordered, or there isn't some fixed size, then I suppose you have to group by some property in HourlyData and then map it. This does not preserve Sequence status.

```
var dailyInfo: Sequence<DailySummary> = hourlyInfo
  .groupBy(HourlyData::hourOfDay)
  .map { (hour, listOfHourlyData) -> DailySummary(hour, listOfHourlyData) }
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that all of the detail information must be loaded into memory. If I can ensure that the data is sorted by timestamp, I would like to have an accumulator that focuses on the current hour, and then spits out the summary.